# What are the Archon’s abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The description for [Archon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/archon) reads:

> While in Archon form, your normal abilities are replaced by powerful Archon abilities

But no further information is provided. What does that mean, precisely? Which abilities are replaced, and what abilities replace them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from the [Diablo Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Archon#Archon_Abilities):

> - **Arcane Blast**
>     Cooldown: 5 seconds
>     Release a wave of pure energy dealing 115% weapon damage as Arcane to all nearby enemies.
> - **Arcane Strike**
>     Strike the ground in front of you, causing 250% weapon damage as Arcane to enemies in the area.
> - **Disintegration Wave**
>     Thrust a beam of pure energy forward dealing 300% weapon damage as Arcane.

The following abilities are unlocked with the skill's runes, so the player has to choose which one to use:

> - **Slow Time**  (20 seconds cooldown)
>     Project a bubble of warped space and time that moves with you, slowing the movement and attack speed of enemies by 40% and the speed of projectiles by 60% for 10 seconds
> - **Teleport**  (10 seconds cooldown)
>     Teleport through the ether to the selected location up to 20 yards away.

All of the Archon's skills completely replace your wizard abilities, until you revert to your normal form, either by waiting or right-clicking on the buff above the hotbar.

Comment: Unfortunately AS does *not* cause 1000% weapon damage.

Comment: @ThiefMaster can you point me to a source that reports the correct values? I got these from the wiki, but I thought they were a little off.

Comment: Ingame tooltips. I'll give you the values later; don't have D3 on my laptop.

Comment: Also, Arcane Blast cd is much, much shorter.

Comment: WHere is the official blizzard reference anyway?

Comment: @JimThio nowhere to be found. On Battle.net there's only the description of the Archon ability, without the skills. That's the reason why this question exists.

Answer (score 0):

You gain the following abilities when changing in to Archon:

- **Arcane Blast** *Cooldown: 120 seconds*
  Release a wave of pure energy dealing 100% weapon damage as Arcane to all nearby enemies.
- **Arcane Strike**  Strike the ground in front of you, causing 1000% weapon damage as Arcane to enemies in the area.
- **Cancel**    Release the powers of the Archon and return to your natural form.
- **Disintegration Wave** Thrust a beam of pure energy forward dealing 1000% weapon damage as Arcane.
- **Slow Time** (Rune effect)  *Cooldown: 120 seconds* Project a bubble of warped space and time that moves with you, slowing the movement and attack speed of enemies by 40% and the speed of projectiles by 60% for 10 seconds
- **Teleport** (Rune effect)   *Cooldown: 120 seconds* Teleport through the ether to the selected location up to 1 yards away.

[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Archon#Archon_Skills)

Comment: The source is not accurate.